# Basic Multiple Image Upload to replace standard image uploader

Tags: media

First question on Drupal Answers, hi everyone.
Starting off with a very basic question actually:

While the standard single image at a time uploader is swell and all, I've got the Galleria module installed, and we have hundreds of photos to upload across multiple albums, and a ton more to come along in The near future. Quite simply is there an existing package/mod that can transform that single image uploader into a multiple image uploader, One where you can select multiple images in the browse window?

Answer (score 1):

The best multiple image uploader that I have found is http://drupal.org/project/plupload (example widget is on [their website](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php))

Also if you are working with images and are using drupal 7, you may also wish to check out http://drupal.org/project/media - this modules is looking more and more promising, and now has views integration as well. It also works with the above recommended plupload module)

Comment: I seem to have issues getting plupload configured. Its installed and enabled, but i cant find any clear cut english documentation about getting it to run on my D7 installation, especially to replace the Image field :\ Its the only module ive installed that i honestly have no clue what to do with lol

Comment: Try using this module as well http://drupal.org/sandbox/vingborg/1138512 - according to the README http://drupalcode.org/project/plupload.git/blob/refs/heads/master:/README.txt - plupload only provides a form element

Answer (score 1):

Plupload does not work on its own. I suggest using a combination of [Multiupload Filefield Widget](https://drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget) and [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](https://drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget). This is as close to the core as possible. It will allow you to hold `Ctrl` + select files, to upload multiple files.

Once the modules are installed, simply change the Widget Type of the image field to Multiupload.

[image]

Comment: Been over a year, but do you know how to make it so that the multiupload images show a preview of the image like the standard image upload does?

Answer (score 1):

You may try [File Resumable Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_resup):

**File Resumable Upload** aka **file_resup** adds large files multiple and resumable upload to the File and Image field widgets.