# Multiple Image upload in drupal 7

Tags: media

I want to upload mulitple image at a time , for more clarification i have mention below link

http://www.olx.com.pk/posting.php?categ_id=378

when you click on add photos , you can upload 20 picture at a time.

Comment: Drupal version 6 or 7?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered [before](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19398/basic-multiple-image-upload-to-replace-standard-image-uploader), but I can't mark it as a duplicate or flag.

You can use the the [Plupload](http://drupal.org/project/plupload) module to allow multiple uploads and even set limits by going into the [code](http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=695).

Comment: I believe Plupload cannot work on its own. It's designed to work with other modules. If someone can please confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/project/swfupload is a widely-used multiple image upload module. There are installation instructions [here](http://drupal.org/files/issues/SWFupload.pdf) and if you run into issues be sure to read through the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/swfupload?status=All&categories=All) before posting a support ticket!

How to install SWFUpload for Drupal 7:

1. Download the [FileField module](http://drupal.org/project/filefield).
2. Download the [jQuery Plugin Handler](http://drupal.org/project/jqp) (jQp) module. This module is required for
   loading the SWFUpload javascript library.
3. Place both modules, as well as the SWFUpload module, in your module
   directory.
    (`sites/all/modules`)
4. If you do not have created a 'libraries' directory yet, create one.
    (`sites/all/libraries`)
5. Create a new directory called 'swfupload' inside the 'libraries' folder.
    (`sites/all/libraries`)
6. Download the [SWFUpload 2.2.0.1 release](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/downloads/list).
7. Copy the files 'swfupload.swf' and 'swfupload.js' to the swfupload folder 
   inside the libraries folder. The end result will read:
    `sites/all/libraries/swfupload/swfupload.js` and
    `sites/all/libraries/swfupload/swfupload.swf`
8. Enable this module by navigating to:
    `admin/build/modules`
9. Ensure the library is available by visiting:
    `admin/build/jqp/swfupload/`

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget.

Used with his little brother 
http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget, it should do the trick.

Really easy to install.

Comment: This should be the ideal choice for multiple image/file option. This module is as close to core as it gets, but lets you hold ctrl + select files to upload multiple.

Answer (score 0):

go for module plupload

[relationship]
(http://drupal.org/project/plupload

kindly go through readme.txt for more information regarding module.